# How to get rid of @{Alias=}?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm experiencing a problem where I have the result below, I have no idea what to search for help in resolving it myself...

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$Usernames | ForEach-Object {Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "XXXXXX" -User "DOMAIN\$_" -Accessright Fullaccess -InheritanceType all -whatif}

User or group "DOMAIN\@{Alias=XXXXXXX}" wasn't found. Please make sure you've typed it correctly.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-MailboxPermission], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 2BB02DBA,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.AddMailboxPermission
    + PSComputerName        : XXXXXXXXXX
```

How could I remove the `@{Alias=}`? I want a plain username...

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$Usernames | Get-Member


   TypeName: Selected.Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.ReducedRecipient

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
Alias       NoteProperty System.String Alias=XXXXXX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `$Usernames` contains objects with a property `Alias`. Expand the property before passing the items into the loop:

```
$Usernames | Select-Object -Expand Alias | ForEach-Object { ... }
```

or use a subexpression to get the value of the property inside the username string:

```
$Usernames | ForEach-Object {
  Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "XXXXXX" -User "DOMAIN\$($_.Alias)" ...
}
```